# Need to exclude few words from logs using grok

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

Consider the below string

`date 00:00 1.1.1.1 POST test.com hello-world`

How could I print only the date totaltime and URL(test.com) using grok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sample above

```
^%{DATA:date} %{DATA:time} %{IP:ip} %{DATA:method} %{DATA:url} %{GREEDYDATA:path}$
```

would generate:

```
{
  "date": [
    [
      "date"
    ]
  ],
  "time": [
    [
      "00:00"
    ]
  ],
  "ip": [
    [
      "1.1.1.1"
    ]
  ],
  "method": [
    [
      "POST"
    ]
  ],
  "url": [
    [
      "test.com"
    ]
  ],
  "path": [
    [
      "hello-world"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Afterwards you can mutate it whichever form you want